# Rails - create child and child's child at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an association where `user` has_many `user_items` and `user_items` has_many `user_item_images`.  With an already exiting `user`. I can create a new `user_item`

```
user_item = user.user_items.create(name: 'foo')
```

and I can create a new `user_item_image`

```
user_item.user_item_images.create(picture: file)
```

But I have a validation on `user_item` where a `user_item` can't exist without a `user_item_image`.

How can I create these two at the same time?

Comment: Use `build` in both cases and call `user_item.save` at the end.

Comment: Ok, do I have to build each one separately?

Comment: You can chain the `create` calls if you want: `user.user_items.create(name: 'foo').user_item_images.create(...)`. Note that using `create!` is usually safer since it'll explode in a spectacular way if it fails, so you can `rescue` accordingly.

Comment: @tadman - It won't get through the validation, will it?

Comment: Ah, you're right. If you've got a circular dependency you need to adjust your validator to chill out on the `create` step or you can never make it work.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by chill out on the create step?  Remove the requirement requirement of having a `user_item_image`?

Comment: You need to relax your validations in order to allow this to happen, they can be set to trigger only on initial create or only on updates, or use the approach advocated by BroiSatse below which I think is also a good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `build` both items and then save the parent. This will work because:

1. Validations are only called when saving the object in the database
2. Saving unsaved parent automatically saves all associated objects (via has_one and has_many, belongs_to object won't be saved without autosave option)
3. Validation is (most likely) based on the association and association includes non-saved but assigned objects in its target. Note however that you cannot use `count` in your validation, as it performs `COUNT` query and non-saved objects won't be included. Use `size` instead, or to be super sure (as `size` calls count for non-loaded associations) `.to_a.size`

Your code should like like:

```
user_item = user.user_items.build(name: 'foo')
user_item.user_item_images.build(picture: file)
user_item.save! # Bang for safety. If in controller, you can fork with if instead
```

Comment: What do you mean by bang for safety?

Comment: I used `save!` instead of `save`. The exlamation mark at the end of method name is comonly referred as bang and the method itself is a `banged version`. Which one you need to use depends on the place and the way this creation is expected to be used in your code. If this is to be model method, add bang to the method name and use banged version. In controller, you can directly test outcome of un-banged `save`.

Answer (score 1):

BroiSatse has a correct answer.  If you really want to do it in one single line you can:

```
user_item = user.user_items.create!(name: 'foo', user_item_images_attributes: { picture: file })
```

In my own code I usually make it look like BroiSatse's code simply for the sake of readability and maintainability - build the initial object, add related items, then save.  It might be a little faster to do it with the single line, but unless you're doing it millions of times it's unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: It seems this requires to first set [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).